# The equivalence of two definitions of Cauchy surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

I see two definitions of a Cauchy surfaces $\Sigma$ of a spacetime $M$.

- a closed achronal subset such that the domain of dependence is $M$
  `i.e. a closed subset where each inextensible time-like curve intersects exactly once and each inextensible causal curve intersects`
- a subset where inextensible time-like curve intersects exactly once

The first one implies the second. Are they really equivalent? Can someone give some reference or proof?

Thanks in advance.

---

Some definitions:

$M$ is a smooth manifold (Hausdorff, connected, no boundary, paracompact)

Lorentzian metric : $g$ a continuous psedo-Riemannian metric on $M$, and at each point, $g$ has signs $(-1,1,\cdots,1)$

time-like: $v\in T_pM$ is time-like $\iff$ $g(v,v)<0$

causal: $v\in T_pM$ is causal $\iff$ $g(v,v)\leq0$

time-orientable: $(M,g)$ is time-orientable $\iff$ there exists a continuous field of time-like vectors.

spacetime: $(M,g)$ with $M$ smooth manifold and $g$ continuous Lorentzian metric and $(M,g)$ is time-orientable

curve: piecewise differentiable, i.e. $\gamma\colon I\to M$ continuous such that except finite many points in $I$, $\gamma'$ exists in the classical sense.

inextensible curve: $\gamma\colon(A,B)\to M$ without the existence of $\lim_{t\to A+}\gamma$ and $\lim_{t\to B-}\gamma$

Comment: Definitions of what is "timelike curve" and "extensibility" could be helpful, as well as "spacetime" (I guess latter one is 4-dimensional pseudoriemannian manifold, but I could be mistaken). I assume it's a standard physicist jargon, but it is completely unknown to me (and probably to most of users here).